# ZeroClipboard doesn't work on popup page's button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, zeroclipboard

I am wondering if there is any way that I can make ZeroClipBoard working on my popup page's buttons?I have the following code so far which will bring a popup page, the popup page is called from a php file include 2 buttons.

code for the first page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">This is the content to get copied to the text area and then to clipboard</div>
<button id="testButton" data-clipboard-target="myDiv"><b>Copy To Clipboard</b></button>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
</script>-->
<button onclick="launchPopUp('', '', 700, 'embedCode.php');">test button</button>
<!--<script>
function test123(){
if(clicks>=1){
alert(clicks);
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('copyAll') );
}
}
</script>-->
</body>
<script>
var client1 = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('testButton') );
</script>
```

I have tried make the "copy to clipboard" for "testButton" button working on my first page by using ZeroClipboard.

my code for second page which will be the content for popup page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$userName =  "asdfbsadf";//$_SESSION['user_name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script type = "text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="copiedContent" style="border: 2px solid; margin: 30px 20px 10px 20px; padding: 4px 3px 5px 3px;">
Here will be the content and <?php echo $userName?> that be copied to the clipboard
</div>
<button id="copyAll" data-clipboard-target="copiedContent" style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;">Copy All</button>

<button style="float: right;" onclick="whatIsThis()">What Is This?</button>

<script>
function whatIsThis(){
    alert("This is...");
}
</script>
</body>
<!--<script language="JavaScript">
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('copyAll') );
</script>-->
</html>
```

the "launchPopup()" function is called from an open source which called popUp2.0.js, if that js file is needed, I will post that, but that one is a 170 lines code.

The comment out codes above are the ones that I tried. I have tried add "var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('copyAll') );" for my popup page's copyAll button to the second page, it didn't work; I tried to add that to first page, the button didn't work also.

I found that if the code "var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('copyAll') );" is called after the button, that will work; but I have tried everything that I know to put it after the button, and when I run the page and click the test button to bring up the popup page, I found the code "var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById('copyAll') );" is always called before the button when I inspect the element.

I'm wondering if I have a function called test123(), is there any way that I can run this function after the button is clicked and the whole popup page is showed, so I can make the Javascript run after the popup page showed, and make the copyAll button working?

Or did I think that in a wrong way and my code is too bad? and if there have any way that can make it work I will appreciate as it's first time I use ZeroClipboard.

Comment: all depends what is launchPopUp

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please remove anything not needed to describe it and be as specific as possible.

Comment: @epascarello Question updated. The code for launchPopUp() is 170 lines long. If you want to see that, I will be happy to update that on my post.

Comment: @greggreg the whole question was updated will more specific code and explanation. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the second function in the onclick event?

```
<button onclick="launchPopUp('', '', 700, 'embedCode.php'); test123();">test button</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, it doesn't work. that will call the test123() before the popup page loaded.